# POST request succeeds on box, but fails in jenkins

Tags: rest, post, jenkins

I have an integration test which connects to salesforce, and gets back an authentication token.

```
    public AuthenticationResponse getAuthenticationResponse()
{
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    map.add("client_id", consumerKey);
    map.add("client_secret", consumerSecret);
    map.add("grant_type", GRANT_TYPE);
    map.add("username", username);
    map.add("password", password);

    return new RestTemplate().postForObject(LOGIN_URI, map, AuthenticationResponse.class);
}
```

^ That's the code the test runs.

```
    public void testConnect(){
    AuthenticationResponse response = dataDotComClient.getAuthenticationResponse();

    assertNotNull(response);
    assertNotNull(response.getAccess_token());
}
```

^ And that's the test itself.

This works fine from my, and other desktops. However, it never works in jenkins, always returning a 400 status code with no real error message behind it. Is there something I have to do in Jenkins to allow post requests to external sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http 400 means

Bad Request - Invalid URL"
OR 
"HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid."

Please make sure that your destination host is reachable from jenkins machine.
Try to login to jenkins machine and run the curl/telnet command to check the connectivity.

Comment: Yup, for whatever reason, that jenkins box could not reach the host.

Comment: You may want to check with your network team to get it fixed.